# Creating a directory and not being able to access it - Scala Play Framework

Tags: scala, file, playframework, jvm, sbt

I am trying to deploy a code written in Play Framework for Scala. I run sbt testProd or sbt dist and then I run the .sh generated in bin folder. In both ways, there is a point in the code where it creates a folder called "floor_plans". However, immediately after the folder is created, there is a verification to check if the folder is a directory and it returns false, which is very strange, because I can see that the folder has been created and it has the proper permissions.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
val dir = new File("floor_plan/building/fl0")

dir.mkdirs()

// I've checked in the terminal and I can see that the directory is 
// created with success and it has rwx permission for the owner, the 
// group, and rx for others.

if (!dir.isDirectory || !dir.canWrite() || !dir.canExecute()) {

      // Although the folder is created and has the proper permission,
      // the codes enter in this if, i.e.  dir.isDirectory is false and 
      // so  canWrite and canExecute

      Logger.debug("Floor plans directory is inaccessible!!")

      throw new AnyPlaceException("Floor plans directory is 
       inaccessible!!!")
    }
```

--

I have run a bunch of tests and found that when I create a simple directory with no subdirectory, this problem does not occur. I think the problem is with the subdirectories.

`val dir = new File("floor_plan/building/fl0")`

`dir.mkdirs()  // this returns true, and I checked that all subdirectories as created with success`

`dir.isDirectory // this returns false only is there is a subdirectory. If I create a directory with no subdirectory, e.g. new File("floor_plan"), the return is true`

The odd part is that when I run this on Intellij, it works fine. But when I run on command line with sbt testProd, dir.isDirectory returns false every time.

I was thinking that mybe Intelij is using a diferrent jvm version, but that does not seems to be the case.

It would be nice to know why this happens, and why it works on IntelliJ and it doesn't on terminal.

Comment: One suggestion for debugging this is check what the return value of mkdirs is (true on success), as well as each of the return values in your exists checks.

Comment: dir.mkdirs(), itself returns true or false whether directory is present is right?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29

Comment: I notice that you write about a directory called “floor_plans”, but in the code, you’re using a directory “floor_plan” (no “s”). Further, note that `dir` still represents the subdirectory “floor_plan/building/fl0”. The existence of “floor_plan” doesn’t prove the existence of “building/fl0” within it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. The return value of mkdirs is true. The typo in floor_plans does not exists in the code, only in the question I made here.